# Reading txt file into R, which is separated by "not" sign (¬)

Tags: r

I'm trying to read a large file into **R** which is separated by the "not" sign (**¬**). What I normally do, is to change this symbol into semicolons using **Text Edit**, and save it as a csv file, but this file is too large, and my computer keeps crashing when I try to do so. I have tried the following options:

```
my_data <- read.delim("myfile.txt", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, quote = "", sep = "\t")
```

which results in a dataframe with a single row. This makes sense, I know, since my file is not separated by tabs, but by the not sign. However, when I try so change sep to ¬ or \¬, I get the following message:

```
Error in scan(file, what = "", sep = sep, quote = quote, nlines = 1, quiet = TRUE,  : 
  invalid 'sep' value: must be one byte
```

I have also tried with

```
my_data <- read.csv2(file.choose("myfile.txt"))
```

and

```
my_data <- read.table("myfile.txt", sep="\¬", quote="", comment.char="")
```

getting similar results. I have searched for options similar to mine, but his kind of separator is not commonly used.

Comment: What about using gsub first, then saving the file and then reopening it? e.g. replacing the not sign with ";". my_data <- gsub("¬", ";", my_data)

Comment: Have you tried a double escape character (which you usually need in R) - i.e. `sep="\\¬"`?

Comment: @AndrewGustar tried it, got the same message: Error in scan(file, what = "", sep = sep, quote = quote, nlines = 1, quiet = TRUE,  : 
  invalid 'sep' value: must be one byte

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to read in a `pipe`d translation of it.

Setup:

```r
writeLines("a¬b¬c\n1¬2¬3\n", "quux.csv")
```

The work:

```r
read.csv(pipe("tr '¬' ','  < quux.csv"))
#   a b c
# 1 1 2 3
```

If commas don't work for you, this works equally well with other replacement chars:

```r
read.table(pipe("tr '¬' '\t'  < quux.csv"), header = TRUE)
#   a b c
# 1 1 2 3
```

The `tr` utility is available on all linuxes, it should be available on macos, and it is included in Rtools for windows (as well as git-bash, if you have that).

If there is an issue using `pipe`, you can always use the `tr` tool to create another file (replacing your text-editor step):

```r
system2("tr", c("¬", ","), stdin="quux.csv", stdout="quux2.csv")
read.csv("quux2.csv")
#   a b c
# 1 1 2 3
```

Comment: The use of `tr` replaces your manual text-editor step. It works very quickly, programmatically, and can be `pipe`d directly into a `read.delim` or similar R function call.

Comment: I finally tried ```test <- read.csv2(pipe("tr '¬' ';'  < myfile.txt"))``` and it worked wonderfully, you have made my life so much easier.