# Reading a txt file separated by "¬" in R

Tags: r, dataframe, read-data, txt

I'm trying to read a txt file in R with read.table. The data is separated with an ¬, but I have a problem with all the column names and the data read, I think it doesn't properly recognize that character.

```
data <- read.table(file="SB11_20191.TXT", sep="¬", quote="", header = TRUE)
```

The problem I get is that all the read cells have a rare character "Â" at the end.

For example: VAR_1Â

I don't know which function should I use for importing the data with that particular character.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a few lines of the text file? Have you tried other read functions like `data.table::fread` or `readr::read_table`?

Comment: Relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/q/64172815/3358272

Comment: FabiánPallares, I feel confident that your question is duplicate of that linked question, and will mark as such (a dupe) shortly. If it doesn't work, please [edit] your question with whatever happens when you try the answer code and things still don't work. (If you need to go that route, it will help to see the top few lines of your data file.) Thanks!